# Multiple relationships and a self relation in UML

Tags: uml

I have a class  and I am creating a relation say `Rel1` between 2 objects of that class and another relation `ParentRel1` between the objects of the same class .

The cardinality of this relation is such that there can be only 1 relation (Rel1) between `Obj1` and `Obj2` 
and multiple relations (`ParentRel1`) between `Obj1` and (many objects).
Also `Obj1` should have a relation with Parent Relation before the `Rel1` can be created .
Same object `Obj1` can be on the right side of any other object .I was wondering how to represent this in a UML diagram

I tried and came up with this

[image]

but I am doubting the cardinality of the relationship .If someone could help in coming up with the correct UML diagram and kind of explain the cardinality

Comment: Please show what you have done so far

Comment: The bad part is I cannot post an image since I dont have 5 points.I cannot post an image .I will try for a way to post my image

Comment: @PrakashParasuraman then upload your image to a free image hosting site and add the link to your question

Comment: Your statements "Also Obj1 should have a relation with Parent Relation before the Rel1 can be created. Same object Obj1 can be on the right side of any other object" are uncomprehensible. Why are you trying to state your question in an abstract way ("Rel1", "Obj1", etc.) when you are not able to express yourself in a clear manner?

Comment: @xmojmr The image is presented at [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/105zcw2.png

Comment: `Rel1` in your question is represented by `Child relation` in your picture and `ParentRel1` in your question is represented by `Parent Relation` in your picture? `Obj1` and `Obj2` are both instances of class `Class1` and you use them to illustrate the constraints of the relationships? Would there be another `Obj3` representing the parent? Can you give the us some less abstract names instead of the `ParentRel1`, `Rel1`, `Class1` (something like `tree`, `bird`, `twig`, `hangs`, `grows`, `swims`..)?

Comment: In my case the Parent or child relation is an object that contains referencese to instances of Class1 which is why I have called it a relationship.We can call it "references" meaning An object points to another object of the same class .I hope this is clear .But again a "special reference" exists between 2 objects which is only 1 .You can call it "Special Reference" relationship "is a " type of "references" relationship which is what i was not able to represent it in the diagram .I hope you see what i am trying to solve here.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you say:

```
between Obj1 and (many objects).
```

What you are looking for is a [N-ary association](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21325949). If you want a [more academic](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10270-002-0009-3) reference on the topic, the access might be restricted.

The different relationships of the association have their own cardinality.

N-ary associations take a lot of sense on a pure modeling point of view. But when it comes to practical OOP representation (for example in reverse engineering), it becomes far more complicated.